# Eclipse code fomatting

Tags: javascript, eclipse, twig

I have some twig files that are a mixture of JavaScript, HTML, and twig markup. Is there a way with Eclipse to hi-lite a section of code and format it as, say JavaScript, then hi-lite another section and format it as HTML? I tried association the file type *.twig with the JavaScript editor, but, I do not seem to get any formatting. Syntax highlighting and code completion would be good too.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. If you have HTML/JS editors available (eclipse classic has them by default).

1. Go to preferences and:  General > Editors > File Associations and add `*.twig` as a new file type and then add HTML editor (in the bottom panel) to it.
2. Then go to: General > Content Types, click on Text/HTML node (in Content Types box) and add `*.twig` file association in the bottom panel.

I've checked this and it works.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, and, I had started out trying this. I had missed your step #2 above regarding Content Types.  But, this is not working for me yet.  What I notice is, Eclipse does not put up a "Source" menu on the main menu bar. I am guessing that is the issue.  Any idea why Eclipse would not be noticing the twig as source? FWTW, JavsScript and HTML formatting work for files that are *.js and *.html respectively.

Comment: Here's the problem. My files are named *.html.twig (i.e. index.html.twig) which seems to be throwing eclipse off.

Comment: @DooDah I've tried a file with the name `index.html.twig` and it still works as described (extension should still be `*.twig`)

Comment: I seem to have one file this is failing for. I am guessing it is not parsing correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find a plugin that will support twig files and provide syntax highlighting. The [Twig Eclipse Plugin](http://twig.dubture.com/) looks promising as it at least seems to support HTML and twig markup together.